# Add image in database and display in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, image

I just need a bit of guidance here. I have alot of images, and each one of these images will have some specific information. How do I add the images in and database and retrieve it to display on the page? I know that there is 'paperclip' but most example requires a form and the user to upload an image.

Comment: You dont store the actually image, you store its loctation or enough information to figure it out on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how your database is set up, I would probably create a table that saved URLs that pointed to images but not actually store the image files themselves within your app.

I use Amazon's S3 service to store all of my graphics and pictures. It's fast, easy and free to use. Just head to http://aws.amazon.com and sign up to try it out if you choose to go that route.

Once you've uploaded them there you can just reference them using their links within your application. If you're using Heroku, by chance, you'll need to be using an outside service to store image assets anyways.

Hope this helps but let me know if you need more granularity on how this would look or how to handle the basics of AWS S3 uploading/linking.